# converting from Purescript Record to a JS object

Tags: javascript, purescript

I am trying to convert a Record to a vanilla JS object

```
module MyModule where

data Author = Author { name :: String, interests :: Array String }

phil :: Author
phil = Author { name: "Phil", interests: ["Functional Programming", "JavaScript"] }
```

when I access the object from JS

```
MyModule.phil
```

it contains other properties that I am not interested in (`value0`)

```
{"value0":{"name":"Phil","interests":["Functional Programming","JavaScript"]}}
```

how do you marshal the Records from the Purescript world to JS?

Comment: did you try: `JSON.stringify(MyModule.phil["value0"])` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyModule.phil))["value0"]` ?

Comment: that would work but that is not what I am asking here. There must be a way in Purescript to convert Records to js objects. I'm guessing it is in the purescript-argonaut or purescript-foreign packages but only see refs to JSON decoding and not js object literals.

Comment: Try using `newtype` instead of `data`.

Comment: don't newtypes only take one arg? How do you model complex records that need to be accessed from js?

Comment: ps. I was just working through the AddressBook example in your book and was trying to see if I could mix JS and Purescript. Are you saying that data Records or Data.Lists can't be accessed in a sane way from JS?

Comment: Sorry, I just tried using records for newtype and it worked. Thanks @PhilFreeman

Comment: Records are first class values in purescript, so a `newtype` works here because the record may have many fields, but is still one value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In section [10.16](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-working-with-untyped-data) of *Purescript By Example*, Phil Freeman shows an example of a `newtype` wrapping a record:

```
newtype FormData = FormData 
   { firstName :: String
   , lastName  :: String
   , street    :: String
   , city      :: String
   , state     :: String
   , homePhone :: String
   , cellPhone :: String 
   }
```

Then in section [10.18](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-serializing-address-book-entries), he writes:

"The `FormData` type is a newtype for a record, so a value of type `FormData` passed to `JSON.stringify` will be serialized as a JSON object. *This is because newtypes have the same runtime representation as their underlying data*."

I think you need to peek under the hood and look at what psc generates to really appreciate this. We'll swap `data` for `newtype`,

```
newtype Author = Author { name :: String, interests :: Array String }

phil :: Author
phil = Author { name: "Phil", interests: ["Functional Programming", "JavaScript"] }
```

and this compiles to

```
// Generated by psc version 0.9.2
"use strict";
var Author = function (x) {
    return x;
};
var phil = {
    name: "Phil",
    interests: [ "Functional Programming", "JavaScript" ]
};
module.exports = {
    Author: Author,
    phil: phil
};
```